# Compare a value to a value in a text file and replace value if higher

Tags: python, file

#Edit whilst editing this question to improve the readability of the question, I accidentally deleted my code attemps, as I thought it was useless comments.

Aim of project:
I am creating a number game where the user has to guess a number between a certain range. Which will work similary to Hot and Colder games. And then if your score beats one of the previous highscores for the game it will be replaced.

Problem:
With this current project I am having a problem with retrieving values from the text file to compare to the score of the player.

Number guessing game with high scores:

```
import pygame
from random import randint
a = True
n = randint(1,10)
guesses = 0

#If scores ever need to be reset just run function
def overwritefile():
    f = open("Numbergame.txt", "w")
    f.close()

#overwritefile()
#Guessing Game Code
while a == True:
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? \nEnter a number!"))
    if guess > n:
        print("Guess is too high! \nTry Again!")
        guesses += 1
    elif guess < n:
        print("Guess is too low! \nTry Again!")
        guesses += 1
    else:
        guesses += 1
        a = False

print("You guessed the number! \nIt was " + str(n) + "\nIt took you: " + str(guesses) + " guesses")

#Adding Score to the file
f = open("Numbergame.txt", "a")
f.write(str(guesses) + '\n')
f.close()



#Compare values and figure out if it is a new highscore
#Maybe I will use the TRY thing got taught recently might help iron out some errors


The two bits that are commented out are my attempts, the first one is one I copied from another question and the second one is my attempt
```

Comment: Focus on one issue at a time. First, read the values from the files into a list. Then, compare the new high score with the values from the list, and change the values in the list if appropriate. Then, write the values from the list back into the file. (Why? It's hard to do [random access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) in files)

Comment: How would I go about reading the value from the file into a list @Codebling?